# How to extract/create ontology ,from public RDF dataset triples?

Tags: dataset, sparql, extract, rdf, ontology

Is there a way to extract the ontology (or schema) implicitly embedded in a public RDF dataset, using SPARQL, or any other tool? (without having to explore the dataset in detail)
This would be for the cases in which there is no explicit ontology for the dataset.
The purpose is to avoid having to explore the dataset in detail, and end up constructing the ontology myself, at the risk of missing important facts or relationships present in the data, and intended to be there by the dataset creator.
Thank you !

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly, but your talking about inducing a schema from the data, right? This is possible by means of machine learning approaches. The paradigm in general is called inductive reasoning, which means from the specific to the general. For example, you could provide a set of individuals for which you want to learn a class description. This could be represented in terms of OWL or SHACL constraint. But it depends on the exact requirements.

Comment: So you need something which provides the different subsets of the RDF resources. Either there are already classes in the dataset, e.g. persons, books, etc. - or you have to do it unsupervised, e.g. via clustering. Then you could simply take the common properties of each cluster

Comment: Hi, how are you? Yes you got it right. I understand what you say. 
To clarify: I need to get datasets to work with, in learning features and making trials. There are many public datasets available which I can use as given, or extract part of them. But when it comes to reasoning and inferencing, having the ontology or schema is a must, am I right? And that is why I wanted to build the ontology from the RDF assertions. Using ML for doing it seems like a whole topic in itself. I will explore it further to see if the effort is worth doing it. Thank you!!